# Create intent and name it as current date and time

Tags: android, android-intent, dynamic, calendar

I am newbie to android. Create intent dynamically with different name. How can it be achieved?
For example I can create using

```
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)
                            getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
           targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

If I want to create same pending intent with different name means then how can i acheive this? Help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case you can use `getBroadcast()` method to set different intent. You can do that by setting different parameter like this

```
int uniqueValue = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        context, uniqueValue, intent, 0);
```

Using this you can uniquely identify intent. Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

if You want to create same pending intent with different name, you can just pass the reference to the new object reference.

```
    PendingIntent oldPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1,intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

    PendingIntent newPeningIntentObject=oldPendingIntent;
```

I don't know how much you can agree with this code according to your requirement. but i show it to take an idea. hope you will help this.

Comment: I already tried succeeded what Androidcodehunter said. Anyway thanks for your valuable answer @Dehan.